# how to make my application work with user iCloud to sync his files

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud

here is my requirement:
I have a application running on iOS 5 and I hope my application is able to get access to user iCloud  to sync some files and then open it.

for example,  user's iCloud has a PDF file, now my application can open PDF file, how to make my application  to get access to user's iCloud  and sync the PDF file to local device and then open it.

I read some guides, looks like I need to enable iCloud on the provision file with my app Id, but every use has different iCloud  app id, should I make a UI to let user input its iCloud user name and pwd ?

could you please show me some steps to get it done ? 
now I even can't upload a PDF into my iCloud .

any answer is welcome,  thanks in advance.

Comment: I need some steps, something like this : 1) enable entitlement on your app project setting, 2) enable iCloud ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to let the user log into iCloud.